# AngularJS application with different customizations

Tags: angularjs, git, deployment, configuration, structure

I got a "framework" created by us using AngularJS. It allows to build questionnaire system and it has many different parameters that control the behavior of framework.

Using this framework we've created 2 projects: `projectA` and `projectB`. The **difference** between these projects are the **settings and assets** (css, img, ...)
Both projects are stored on the same branch in `git` and only `config` file defines the project customization.
I can't think of the best way how these 2 projects can be easily deployed separately from the same code source using `Gulp` or something other.

Here are some ideas I got for the moment:
 1. Have both settings files and images (e.g. `logo_A.png` and `logo_B.png`) in the code and choose appropriate during build using `Gulp`
 2. Create folder `customizations` that will have 2 subfolders `A` and `B` with corresponding settings and assets
 3. Create separate repository for each project installation scripts (not the code) and these scripts will do all the work

**What is the best way in this case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the easieast and most understandible solution was to create additional `custom` folder.

### Assets

In addition to normal application files I got now `custom` folder with 2 subfolders: `A` and `B` each of them containing `assets` (css, img) that correspond only to concrete project.
In `gulp` I've used [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module which allows to pass parameters. After reading project name from input I can looks inside `custom` folder to see if there are resources interesting for me (I've just added `custom` folder into the resources paths).

```
var customPath = './custom/' + app.name;
exports.paths = {
  web: {
    //Resources
    styles: ['./app/**/*.css', './app/**/*.scss', customPath + '/**/*.css', customPath + '/**/*.scss'],
...
```

And the call to build task now looks like this: `gulp build --name A`.

### Configuration

One more thing was done for configuration file of AngularJS that contains constants. I've used [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config) plugin which allows to build AngularJS configuration (constants) file on fly. In my flow, first I check if **custom** configuration file exists inside `custom` folder I use it, if no I'm using default one from application.

```
var getAppScripts = function() {
    return $.eventStream.merge(
        gulp.src(config.paths.web.scripts)
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        //.pipe($.eslint())
        .pipe($.eslint.format()),
        getAppConfig())
            .pipe($.angularFilesort());
};

var getAppConfig = function() {
    var configFile = config.paths.web.custom + "/app.config.yaml";
    if (fs.existsSync(configFile)) {
        return gulp.src(configFile)
            .pipe($.ngConfig(config.app.name, {
                parser: 'yml',
                createModule: false
            }));
    }
    else {
        return gulp.src(config.paths.web.config);
    }
}
```